# Installing Python on FreeBSD 8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, freebsd

So I installed python on my FreeBSD box with these commans:

```
#portsnap fetch

#portsnap extract

#portsnap update

#cd /usr/ports/lang/python32

#make install clean
```

Everything worked and I got no error messages. Installation went smoothly. However when I type python in shell, I get:

```
python: Command not found.
```

Help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can search it:

```
find /usr/bin /bin/ /usr/local/bin -iname 'python*'
```

Comment: Also, if you want to be able to access python2.7 using the keyword `python`, you can easily add it to the defined aliases by using `nano ~/.bashrc` with the code `alias python      python2.7`. Place it after the last alias in the alias section.

Answer (score 8):

I know it's an old post but it is still not completely answered.

Command in accepted answer from [guettli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633961/guettli) will return something like this:

```
$ find /usr/bin /bin/ /usr/local/bin -iname 'python*'
/usr/local/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.6m-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.6
/usr/local/bin/python3.6-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.6m
```

This means that to enter python shell you need to type "python3.6".

To use just "python" you may create a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python
```

If you do not have permissions to create symlink (or you just do not want to), you may also create alias by editing default shells dotfile for your user, e.g. ~/.tcshrc by adding following line:

```
echo 'alias python python3.6' >> ~/.tcshrc
```

Alias will not automatically work in your current session until you relog to shell or "reload" changes in .tcshrc:

```
source ~/.tcshrc
```

By editing dotfile, alias will become permanent.
To create just a temporary alias for current session, you may set alias directly in the shell:

```
alias python python3.6
```

Temporary alias will disappear once you log off but can be "unaliased" in current session:

```
unalias python
```

Comment: I did everything you suggested and it did not help...  Erik Cederstrand got it right...

Comment: I updated the answer with correct dotfile and alias setting to reflect the default shell in FreeBSD (before update it was for bash, which is not default shell in FreeBSD).

Answer (score 1):

What if you type the full path(/usr/local/bin/python)? You probably forgot to type "rehash". Your shell needs to re-build the cache of programs available in your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, but `.bashrc` is wrong choice because problem remains .. see bash(1) manpage

> > When  an  interactive  shell that is **not a login shell** is started, bash
> >            reads and executes commands from ~/.bashrc, if that file exists.

and ..

> > Do  not  read  and  execute  the  personal  initialization  file
> >                   ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive.  This  option  is  **on  by
> >                   default** if the shell is invoked as sh.

**Better solution?**

`echo 'alias python=python2.7' >>~/.bash_profile`

**Update: Real solution according to FreeBSD Release Notes**

`pkg install lang/python`

`which python
/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Erik Cederstrand You are the man, my friend.  Your solution worked for me!  I tried the advice above and nothing happened.  You the man...

Comment: Your "real solution" does not really answer the question - symlink "/usr/local/bin/python" will not be created even if you install python with package manager.
Also original question was about ports - there are legitimate reasons you may want to use ports instead of pkg.